# Display System DateTime In Output Window During Visual Studio 2008 Build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-process

Does anyone know how to set Visual Studio 2008 to output the current date/time at the end of a build?  I've set it to output verbose but that just shows the date/time at build start plus elapsed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253960/cant-get-log4net-to-work-in-my-asp-net-website) a while back and found the answer was to use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net) and use a [TraceAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TraceAppender.html).

If you need some more help about Log4Net, etc.. just ask away.

There's also a [really kewl application called DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) (by the infamously awesome SysInternals krew) that allows you to debug to an external app .. and watch it log, live!

From the L4N FAQ ...

> The Trace system will by default send
>   the message to an attached debugger
>   (where the messages will appear in the
>   output window). If the process does
>   not have a debugger attached then the
>   messages are sent to the system
>   debugger. A utility like DebugView
>   from http://www.sysinternals.com  may
>   be used to capture these messages.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/bb896647.DebugView(en-us,MSDN.10).gif))</sub>

Comment: The question was specifically about the native Visual Studio output window, not another logging tool.

Answer (score 8):

A new way I found is to call the `Time` command in the post event *Post-build event command line:*

```
TIME /T
```

Comment: this works well in VS2015 - It's simple and elegant. thanks!

Comment: Also confirmed working in VS2017.  This answer is much better than adding a whole bunch of new 3rd party stuff to VS as in the currently accepted answer.